# The right way to present view controller with custom transition/animation in iOS<7

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, transition

I want to present view controllers as simple as with native `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` methods, but use custom animations for this.

The common way to do this is to perform custom animation (using view screenshots instead of view itself) and call `presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:…` after.

But in this case view controller **life-cycle messages are sent not in time**. `viewWillApper:` and `viewDidAppear:` sent together instead of normal way: the first one just before animation and the last — after. Also they sent with `animated` parameter set to `NO`.

The other bad thing is that screenshot of a view (for animation) captured before `viewWillApper:` called. So it can be some outdated, and this will cause flicking at the end of animation.

I've searched lot of related projects on github/cocoapods (SO answers too), but did not find any with the right life-cycle of presented view controller. *There are sometimes even worse solutions like simple views changing without any calls to life-cycle methods.*

---

**Possible solutions I know**:

- iOS7 — *I can't, I need it in iOS6 too*
- Use transition between contained view controllers — *Not as simple and reusable as "modal presenting"*
- Use tricky animations like [here](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFFadeBackModalAnimation) — *my animation can't be implemented in similar way*
- *While writing this question I thought about custom segue with overridden `perform:` method. But looks like it's  not easy too. At least I don't know how to use it without storyboard and how to do dismiss in easy way.*

---

**Do you know how to present view controller with custom animation in iOS6 and make it's life-cycle happy?**

---

**Update**: finally I've decided to use *container view controller*. It has ability to customize transitions of it's children and preserve VC's life-cycle. The bad side: it's not as easy as custom transitions in iOS7. It needs container, making xib some harder. And needs additional code to support.

Comment: I haven't used custom segues myself, but my (little) understanding of them is that they were introduced for situations like this.